# Can I use "nail down something" if that thing is in my head?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm talking about how to develop a paragraph. I want to say that if I can successfully think of an example, the rest will be easy. So, the example is in my head. I've not written it down. In this case, can I use "nail down"? I read some sample sentences in the dictionary, and it seems that "nail down" can only be used with something that has already happened.

> The rest of the paragraph will be easy to write if you **nail down** the
> example.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fit any of the definitions at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nail%20down). Have you looked elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see it perhaps working if you just use 'nail' rather than 'nail down'.

> If I can just nail this first sentence, then the rest will come easy.

This is using 'nail' as a verb, meaning 'to succeed'.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nail

'Nail down' has some kind of impression of 'fastening into place permanently' that just 'nail' *might* not hold so firmly. I honestly can't nail the distinction [pardon the pun] but there *is* one somewhere. The trouble with trying to find a good dictionary definition or writer's illustration is, of course, that you get far too many woodworking results to be useful.